# What does extensive Z-offset processing in Creality 4.8 slicer mean? How does it differ from a simple Z-offset setting?

Tags: bed-leveling, print-axis-offset

I am facing a problem where the nozzle begins scrapping **only on one side** of the print as the print thickness builds up on the bed. I am building a skirt comprising 10 rasters as well and over there the bed level appears to be pretty uniform on all sides around the print.

In this context, I wanted to understand what the extensive Z-offset processing means and if this could address the problem I am facing. The Z-offset setting I have is -0.06 mm in the slicer and -3.15 mm on the printer. There is no scrapping on any other side of the printed object.

I also want to understand why the build plate adhesion setting (highlighted in the image) is shown as off while I am building a skirt around the print which is set up from the build plate adhesion setting.

[image: Screenshot of Creality Slicer 4.8 with the 'Extensive Z Offset Processing' option highlighted]

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: The **Extensive Z Offset Processing** option changes the G-code for *any/all* Z movement.

According to an answer by fieldofView on the GitHub question [Z-Offset incrementing in some situations?](https://github.com/fieldOfView/Cura-ZOffsetPlugin/issues/19#issuecomment-803526014):

> You can try setting the "Extensive Z Offset Processing" option. **This will change all the Z coordinates in the gcode instead of manipulating the coordinate system.** [bold mine]

I was able to confirm this from an answer by ahoeben on the Ultimaker Community question [Cura settings: Improving naming and descriptions](https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/33279-cura-settings-improving-naming-and-descriptions/?do=findComment&comment=269837):

> This is provided by the Z Offset plugin (which - coincidentally - I wrote). Keeping this setting "off" is much faster, since it only needs to insert a couple of lines of code. **Turning the setting on will need to process the whole gcode file and modify all moves that have a Z value. The option is there because the better, faster way does not work on some specificly broken firmware versions and printers.** [bold mine]

Comment: BTW, I turned the extensive z-offset setting on and the problem did not go away. I was printing ASTM D638 type I specimens.